# Can I specify endianness when reinterpreting as a float?

Tags: c, endianness, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am writing a C program that communicates over modbus TCP. I send the float `3.14` on my modbus client, with a hexadecimal representation of `0x4048F5C3`. My C code is correctly receiving the modbus packet, and now I just need to reinterpret the `unsigned char *buffer` as a float so I can get the value `3.14`. Here is my code

```
int main()
{
    setup_modbus_tcp();
    unsigned char buffer[4] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    get_modbus_data(buffer, 4);
        //Buffer now holds { 0x40, 0x48, 0xF5, 0xC3 };
    float value = *(float *)buffer;
        //value is now -490.564453
}
```

Now, I can tell that this problem is because of endianness, because if I swap endianness so that the buffer looks like this:

```
{ 0xC3, 0xF5, 0x48, 0x40 };
```

then everything works fine. But this feels a little bit messy. Do I have to swap endianness? Or is there a way that I can specify endianness when I do:

```
float value = *(float *)buffer;
```

Comment: Either you have to swap all bytes or you send the float as a printed ASCII string.

Comment: Even after byte-swapping: Are you shure the representation is identical?

Comment: @Olaf Yes, after byte swapping, it's definitely correct. There is a minor difference because of floating point precision, but other than that it's right.

Comment: Either the encoding is the same or not. If they are the same, they have the same precision, otherwise they have a different encoding. Mind that C does not enforce a specific floating point format/encoding, but only defines relevant decimal paramters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer must be handled manually, this includes changes to endianness. A function can always be used that converts the buffer to a floating point format.

```
float value = Convert( buffer );
```

---

To add, you way of converting the buffer is incorrect:

```
float value = *(float *)buffer;
```

An array of unsigned chars cannot be simply to a `float` type, as it causes undefined behavior. The memory must be copied to an object of type `float`:

```
float value;
memcpy( &value , buffer , sizeof( value ) );  //assumes endianness has already been handled
```